# Из-за чего может возникнуть разница между UTC и GMT в PHP скрипте?

Tags: php, centos, utc

Имеется 2 сервера (CentOS), один и тот же php скрипт отрабатывает по разному. Точнее, имеет разный оффсет для UTC и GMT временных зон, но они находятся в одном часовом поясе и не имеют разницы во времени (буквально секунда).

Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего может возникнуть следующее поведение/коллизия?

**Вводные данные**:

- **Первый сервер**:

  `date -u` = Tue Dec 28 07:29:41 UTC 2021

  `date +'%:z %Z'` = +00:00 GMT

  `zdump /etc/localtime` = Tue Dec 28 07:30:21 2021 GMT

  `ls -l /etc/localtime` = /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Dakar

  `(new \ReflectionExtension('date'))->info();` =

  ```
   date/time support => enabled
   timelib version => 2018.03
   "Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
   Timezone Database => internal
   Default timezone => UTC

   Directive => Local Value => Master Value
   date.timezone => no value => no value
   date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
   date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
   date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
   date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333`
  ```
- **Второй сервер**:

  `date -u` = Tue Dec 28 07:31:01 UTC 2021

  `date +'%:z %Z'` = +00:00 UTC

  `zdump /etc/localtime` = Tue Dec 28 07:31:29 2021 UTC

  `ls -l /etc/localtime` = /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC

  `(new \ReflectionExtension('date'))->info();` =

  ```
   date/time support => enabled
   timelib version => 2018.03
   "Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
   Timezone Database => internal
   Default timezone => UTC

   Directive => Local Value => Master Value
   date.timezone => no value => no value
   date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
   date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
   date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
   date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333`
  ```
- В php.ini настройка временных зон опущена, строка закомментирована.

**Сам скрипт**:

```
$tz = new \DateTimeZone("UTC");
$dt = new \DateTime('now', $tz);
var_dump("UTC offset: " . $tz->getOffset($dt));

$tz1 = new \DateTimeZone("GMT");
$dt1 = new \DateTime('now', $tz1);
var_dump("GMT offset: " . $tz1->getOffset($dt1));

$tz2 = new \DateTimeZone("Africa/Dakar");
$dt2 = new \DateTime('now', $tz2);
var_dump("Africa/Dakar offset: " . $tz2->getOffset($dt2));

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump((new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T'));
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
var_dump((new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T'));
```

**Результат на первом сервере (поведение с коллизией при timezone=UTC):**

```
string(17) "UTC offset: 10800"  <-- коллизия

string(13) "GMT offset: 0"      <-- нет коллизии

string(22) "Africa/Dakar offset: 0"

string(23) "2021-12-28 10:24:23 MSK"

string(23) "2021-12-28 07:24:23 GMT"
```

**Результат на втором сервере (ожидаемое поведение):**

```
string(13) "UTC offset: 0"  <-- идентично GMT

string(13) "GMT offset: 0"  <-- идентично UTC

string(22) "Africa/Dakar offset: 0"

string(23) "2021-12-28 07:25:21 UTC"

string(23) "2021-12-28 07:25:21 GMT"
```

Comment: А что показывает `ls -l /etc/localtime` ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen На сервере с коллизией показывает: `/etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Dakar`, т.е. `+00:00`.
Сервер второй, без коллизии: `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`

Comment: Ну так может нужно их привести к одному варианту и не заморачиваться?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я пытаюсь однозначно разобраться и найти точное решение, нет возможности дергать devOps миллион раз, из-за этого, хочется убедиться, что решение сработает. Вы предлагаете привести все либо к одной, либо к другой временной зоне, но они не имеет разницы в смещении, обе интерпретируются как `+00:00`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это может помочь, если у них нет смещения относительно друг друга?

Comment: +10800 это три часа, то есть смещение на +3 часа, посмотрите что отдаёт сервер с коллизией с помощью ``date_default_timezone_get`` мне кажется у вас перебивка дефолтного часового пояса где-то

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev На двух серверах один и тот же результат вывода `date_default_timezone_get = UTC` (проверяю в отдельном php файле, вне любого приложения, инструкция только одна, чтобы не перетереть).

Comment: А что на первом сервере выведет команда `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov `ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`
`-rw-r--r--. 8 root root 1518 Mar 16  2020 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`

Comment: @Borislav что-то он большой для UTC, кажись этот файл повреждён

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, скорее всего вы правы, т.к. `zdump /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC` выдает следующее: `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC  Thu Dec 30 12:41:27 2021 MSK`. Оформите пожалуйста ваш комментарий, как ответ, приму его. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновите на сервере пакет `tzdata` и установите симлинк `/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`